# Trying to simulate textbox

Tags: css

I trying to simulate textbox using CSS

HTML:

```
<div id="event_box" class="margin-bottom-10"></div>

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
<div id='calendar' style="width:100%"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#event_box {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: none;
    width: 318px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

event_box is my textbox,problem is when it get results, them going out the border like:
[image]

What I need to do to keep data received into text box? Regards

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwfdc6wb/)

Comment: Text boxes are treated very differently than normal, block-level elements.  You're not going to get the same functionality without some heavy javascript on top of your CSS.  The closest you can get to it is `overflow:hidden` as Muthu suggests, but even that won't be perfect.  You won't be able to see the trailing characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `overflow` property.

Either overflow:auto to include a horizontal scroll bar in your box, or overflow hidden to silently cut off the text that exceeds the size of the text box.

```
#event_box {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: none;
    width: 318px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: auto; /* OR */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your css:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to break the text:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

If you want to keep just one line, add this:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-height: 1.1em;
```

It's necessary to set the height to keep in one line only.

Answer (score 1):

You need you use `overflow:hidden;` to make sure not going out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
width:318px;
```

Add:

```
display: inline-block;
```